# \refsegment in biblatex broken since update to TL2012

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I'm writing my thesis and I'm using `biblatex` with a `biber` back-end to create a per-chapter bibliography. I recently updated to TL2012 and since then the references to the `refsegments` have broken down and I've been getting a Latex warning: `undefined 'refsegment:1'warning` ever since.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[sorting = none, style=numeric]{biblatex}


\defbibheading{bibintoc}{%
  \section*{References for Chapter \ref{refsegment:\therefsegment}}}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter One}
\begin{refsegment}
\cite{Crabtree:2007vn},\cite{Nault:2005ys}
\cite{Alexeev:1996dq}
\end{refsegment}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\begin{refsegment}
\cite{Sze:2007vn},\cite{Nault:2005ys}
\end{refsegment}

\backmatter

\printbibheading
\bibbysegment[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Changing `refsegment` to `refsection` does fix the problem, but I want to stick with the `refsgement` environment, as it should, and previously did, work; also I'm using the `refsection` environment independently to add the bibliography for an unnumbered introduction.

Here are the contents of the `biblio.bib` file used in the MWE:

```
@techreport{Nault:2005ys,
    Author = {Nault, R. M.},
    Date-Added = {2012-07-18 14:44:40 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2012-07-18 14:45:21 +0000},
    Institution = {Argon National Laboratory},
    Title = {Report on the basic energy sciences workshop on solar energy utilization},
    Year = {2005}}

@article{Crabtree:2007vn,
    Author = {Crabtree, G. W. and Lewis, N. S.},
    Date-Added = {2012-07-18 14:36:51 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2012-07-19 15:42:49 +0000},
    Journal = {Physics Today},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {37},
    Title = {Solar energy conversion},
    Volume = {60},
    Year = {2007}
    }

@article{Alexeev:1996dq,
    Abstract = {{The thermodynamic boundary of excess liquid phase formation during
   molecular beam epitaxy of ternary InGaAs and AlGaAs compounds is
   calculated. The critical As, flux corresponding to the liquid phase
   appearance exhibits a non-monotonic behavior with temperature. The
   strain arising from the mismatch between the lattice constants of the
   substrate and the epitaxial layer significantly influences the boundary
   of the excess liquid formation. For the AlGaAs ternary compounds, the
   temperature gap where the liquid phase is not formed even at the
   absence of the incident As, flux is predicted.}},
    Address = {{PO BOX 211, 1000 AE AMSTERDAM, NETHERLANDS}},
    Affiliation = {{CTR ADV TECHNOL,ST PETERSBURG 198103,RUSSIA.}},
    Author = {Alexeev, AN and Karpov, SY},
    Date-Added = {2011-05-24 16:20:07 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-07-23 08:40:57 +0000},
    Doc-Delivery-Number = {{UL940}},
    Issn = {{0022-0248}},
    Journal = {{JOURNAL OF CRYSTAL GROWTH}},
    Journal-Iso = {{J. Cryst. Growth}},
    Keywords-Plus = {{THERMODYNAMIC ANALYSIS; SEGREGATION; GA1-XALXAS}},
    Language = {{English}},
    Number = {{1-2}},
    Number-Of-Cited-References = {{15}},
    Pages = {15},
    Publisher = {{ELSEVIER SCIENCE BV}},
    Subject-Category = {{Crystallography}},
    Times-Cited = {{7}},
    Title = {{Conditions of excess liquid phase formation during molecular beam epitaxy of III-V ternary compounds}},
    Type = {{Article}},
    Unique-Id = {{ISI:A1996UL94000003}},
    Volume = {{162}},
    Year = {{1996}}}

@book{Sze:2007vn,
    Author = {Sze, S.M. and Ng, K.K.},
    Date-Added = {2012-07-04 15:06:57 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2012-07-05 13:12:17 +0000},
    Publisher = {Wiley-Interscience},
    Title = {Physics of Semiconductor Devices},
    Year = {2007}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New sorting features in `biber` use reference sections. So to avoid multiply-defined labels the reference segment labels now include `\therefsection`. The issue in using the old label format was [reported](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/28) and fixed in `biblatex 2.2`.

Just change your references to:

```
\ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}
```