# Refsegment wrong numbering

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

The following MWE prints a cumulative bibliography, subdivided by chapter, using `biblatex`. However there seems to be a problem with the `\therefsegment` counter because I'm getting "References Chapter 2" instead of "References Chapter 1".

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[refsegment=chapter, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibbook}[\bibname]{\chapter{#1}}
\defbibheading{subbib}[\refname\space\chaptername\space\therefsegment]{\section{#1}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\nocite{*}

\backmatter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} 
\printbibheading[heading=bibbook]
\bibbysegment[heading=subbib]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `refsegment=chapter` is the rough equivalent of invoking `\newrefsegment` before `\chapter`. Part of this issue was brought up in [another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99915). For an example that achieves correct numbering see the manual or [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69139/4483).

Comment: @Audrey That solved my problem! Should I delete my question or you prefer to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference segment numbering starts at zero. The option setting `refsegment=chapter` is the rough equivalent of invoking `\newrefsegment` *before* `\chapter`. This ensures that citations in the chapter titles don't get assigned to the previous reference segment.

The section entitled "Multiple Bibliographies" in the biblatex manual demonstrates how the chapter and reference segment/section numbering can be kept in sync. Here is an excerpt, adapted to your example.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[defernumbers,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\defbibheading{subbibintoc}
  [\refname\ for Chapter \ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}]
  {\section*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{refsegment}
\nocite{glashow,bertram,markey}
\end{refsegment}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{refsegment}
\nocite{companion,ctan,cms}
\end{refsegment}

\backmatter
\chapter{Appendix}
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\bibbysegment[heading=subbibintoc]
\end{document}
```